Is there a way I can view one document at a timeline one after the other from firesafe Firestore in flutter. Like I click a slideshow of documents
I Want to click a button then I get one random document, then I click again then I get another document. I just want to retrieve one document at a time, then I get another one when the user clicks the button and keeps on going on and on
Scrollbar( thumbVisibility: true, child: PaginateFirestore( itemBuilderType: PaginateBuilderType.listView, //Change types accordingly itemBuilder: (context, documentSnapshots, index) { final data = documentSnapshots[index].data() as Map?;       

 return ListTile(

            //leading: const CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.person)),
            title: data == null
                ? const Text('Error in data')
                : Column(
                    children: [
                      // for (var i in data["Picture"]) ...[
                      //
                      //   //Text(data["Picture"].indexOf(i).toString()),
                      //   Text(i),
                      //
                      // ],

                      
                      Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .66,
                        child: CarouselView(itemExtent: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60,
                            shrinkExtent: 200,
                            children: List.generate(data["Picture"].length,
                                  (index) => CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: data["Picture"][index],fit: BoxFit.cover,),),
                            )),

                      InkWell(
                          onTap: (){
                            // for example if i click this button,i should get another document. i dont want to stream them all at once like am doing here
                            // get one document then the next document and so on
                          },
                          child: Center(child: Text("Go to the next document"))),




                    ],
                  ));
      },
      query: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Test')
          .orderBy("ParentId"),
      itemsPerPage: 5,
      // to fetch real-time data
      isLive: true,
    ),
  ),


Yup, that all sounds possible. Did you try getting s single document in your onTap yet?
